# Error using pointer to get value, but it is correct to return directly, why?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
//define class C
class C {
 public:
  C() = default;
  ~C() = default;

  double x() { return x_; }

  void set_x(double x) { x_ = x; }

  double y() { return y_; }

  void set_y(double y) { y_ = y; }

 protected:
  double x_;
  double y_;
};

//define class B
class B {
 public:
  B() = default;
  ~B() = default;

  void set_c(std::vector<C> c) { c_ = c; }

  std::vector<C> c() { return c_; }

  std::vector<C> *mutable_c() { return &c_; }

 protected:
  std::vector<C> c_;
};

//define class A
class A {
 public:
  A() = default;
  ~A() = default;

  B b() { return b_; }

  void set_b(B b) { b_ = b; }

 protected:
  B b_;
};

int main() {
  A a;
  B b;
  C c1, c2;
  std::vector<C> c;
  c1.set_x(11.11);
  c1.set_y(22.22);
  c.push_back(c1);
  c2.set_x(33.33);
  c2.set_y(44.44);
  c.push_back(c2);
  b.set_c(c);
  a.set_b(b);

 //get value
  for (auto it : *(a.b().mutable_c())) {
    std::cout << "111:" << it.x() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "222:" << it.y() << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout<<std::endl;

   //get value
    for (auto it : a.b().c()) {
    std::cout << "333:" << it.x() << std::endl
    std::cout << "444:" << it.y() << std::endl;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Results in the error stated in the title. I do realize that if the first way returns the wrong result, the second way is correct.
But, here I want to understand what is the meaning of this error and why can't I use it this way.

//wrong

111:0

//wrong

222:4.64953e-310

111:33.33

222:44.44

333:11.11

444:22.22

333:33.33

444:44.44

Comment: *"The entire code is as follows"* -- the entire code is inadvisable. You should do some [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to narrow down the problem, to find the point where the values of your variables are not what you expect. Focus on that point and build a [mre] around it.

Comment: You did not include a description of what this program is intended to do, so there is no evidence that the result is wrong, much less why it is wrong. Requests for debugging help should include both the expected and actual results, in addition to a [mre]. It also helps to explain what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Why what?......

Comment: *"results in the error stated in the title"* -- I have two issues with this. First, why is it so hard to copy-and-paste? Why make every reader interrupt the flow of reading to find and re-read the title, instead of having the error message right there? (Lots of people write like this, and I find it annoying at best.) Second, the error message in the title seems like a paraphrase. The error message in the body of your question should be an exact copy of what the compiler told you, including all those explanatory details that beginners tend to not understand (hence overlook). Copy-paste is good.

Comment: You might want to review [ask], especially the parts about asking your question before posting any code. A lot of questions are low-quality because the author tries to use code to ask a question, resulting in ambiguity and confusion. Forcing yourself to write out your situation and question in words -- supported by code, but coming before the code -- often makes the situation clearer to both the reader and the author.

Answer (score 3):

This program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an object after its lifetime has ended.

This is rather subtle. [The range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) is transformed by the compiler into a "normal" iterator-based loop. The first loop in your example turns into this:

```
auto&& __range = *(a.b().mutable_c());
for (auto it = __range.begin(), end = __range.end(); it != end; ++it) {
  // loop body
}
```

The problem: `a.b()` produces a temporary `B` object. Then `__range` is bound to the data member of that temporary. Then the temporary is destroyed, and so is its data member, whereupon `__range` becomes a dangling reference.

The second loop starts with

```
auto&& __range = a.b().c();
```

Here, `a.b().c()` produces a temporary `std::vector<C>` object. This temporary is bound to a reference, which has the effect of [extending its lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary), so it remains alive while the loop is running.

---

In short: binding a reference to a temporary extends its lifetime, but binding a reference to the return value of a member function does not (even if that member function happens to return a pointer or reference to the temporary's data member). The range-for loop syntax hides the fact that there's a reference initialization involved.

Comment: in the first loop ,the first element is wrong,but the second element is correct,why?

Comment: "*binding a reference to a data member of that temporary does not*" how about `auto&& __range = a.b().c_` ? [Lifetime of a temporary](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary) says "*Whenever a reference is bound to a temporary object or to a **subobject** thereof, the lifetime of the temporary object is extended to match the lifetime of the reference*".

Comment: @jiang123456 The behavior is undefined, that means everything could happen and it's meaningless to find out why.

Comment: Q3 section in [this Herb Sutter's post](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/) may be related to this. And [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/177Gse3Mn) seems that binding a reference to a data member of a temporary will extened the lifetime of that complete temporary.

Comment: I guess that `*(a.b().mutable_c())` is lvalue so `auto&&` is deduced to lvalue reference, as [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) saying "*auto&& may be deduced either as an lvalue reference or rvalue reference according to the initializer, which is used in range-based for loop.*".  I'm not sure.

Comment: "the first element is wrong,but the second element is correct,why?" By accident. Undefined behavior is undefined. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior.

Comment: @VainMan "Whenever a reference is bound to a temporary object or to a subobject thereof" Right. My statement was too broad. Binding directly to the data member of the temporary does extend the lifetime; `for (auto elem : a.b().c_)` would have worked if `c_` were accessible. But the example doesn't bind to a data member, but to the return value of a member function; there's no indication that the function does in fact return a pointer to a data member. In this case, no lifetime extension.

Comment: @VainMan Yes, `*(a.b().mutable_c())` is an lvalue, and `__range` will be deduced to lvalue reference. This isn't really relevant to the issue at hand. Both lvalue and rvalue references extend the lifetime of the temporary bound to them. The issue at hand is that `*(a.b().mutable_c())` is not a temporary - nothing says that the pointer returned by `B().mutable_c()` is related in any way to the object `mutable_c()` is called on.